# Atom show methods available to an object and show method docs

Tags: atom-editor

I was watching a video of someone using a code editor. When they put a dot after a class name e.g.

```
Class.
```

the editor would automatically show a list of available methods for that class.

It then also showed the docs/inputs that the method would take.

Does atom have a feature that allows you to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [autocomplete+](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus) what you're searching for?

Comment: I already have that installed and it doesn't seem to do the above.